# Change widget properties by it's controller in flutter

Tags: flutter

let's say I have a `TextField` like this

```
TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController()

...

TextField(
    controller: textController
)
```

and assume I have a library which takes the controller of a `TextField` and prints some text inside it.

is it possible to change the properties of `TextField` or any other widget by it's `controller` ?
for example: disable the `TextField`

if `No` how can I do that inside my library, not inside a `Stateful` widget

Comment: you can create a StatefulWidget with your TextField inside then you can change disable/enable your textfield based  on the logic you want.

Comment: the only thing I have access inside my library is the `controller` of the text . I can't change properties by `controller` then call `setState`

Comment: The TextController cannot disable a field as far as I know

Comment: any workaround or suggestion

Comment: Make a widget instead of whatever you're doing. And internally use a TextField

Answer (score -1):

I created this sample , you can take a look :

class SampleTextField extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          SampleTextFieldState createState() {
            return new SampleTextFieldState();
          }
        }

```
    class SampleTextFieldState extends State<SampleTextField> {
      MyCustomController customController =
          MyCustomController(controller: TextEditingController());

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                MyCustomTextField(
                  customController: customController,
                ),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      customController.controller.text = "new value";
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("set text"),
                ),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      customController.enable = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("disable textfield"),
                ),
                OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      customController.enable = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("enable textfield"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyCustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
      final MyCustomController customController;

      const MyCustomTextField({Key key, this.customController}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextFormField(
          controller: customController.controller,
          enabled: customController.enable,
        );
      }
    }

    class MyCustomController {
      final TextEditingController controller;
      bool enable;

      MyCustomController({@required this.controller, this.enable = true});
    }
```

Comment: dude, I know how to do it inside a `Stateful` widget. thank you. maybe my question is not clear enough and that's because of my bad english. sorry for that. But this is not the right answer